# How to edit the version of an artifact while copying from one repository to another repository in artifactory

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, artifactory

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to **change the version of an artifact** while copying it  from **snapshot** location to the **release** location in artifactory.

I looked up several resources, but no luck. Looks like it's end of road for such a requirement.

My gradle build script generates a pom during the publish(via the MavenPublication) to the snapshot location in the artifactory. But I then want to send the artifacts to the release location by changing their versions on the fly.

Artifactory provides REST apis ,but I'm not able to find any which would fulfill my requirement.

Is there any kind of **REST API provided by artifactory** for this particular requirement(in case I missed on anything) **?**

Below are the links that I came across, among the many I browsed through tirelessly :

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-4416

http://forums.jfrog.org/Generate-POM-for-Artifact-Deployed-via-REST-td6808865.html

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts

Any guidance in this regard is greatly appreciated. I just wonder, why artifactory hasn't created this so handy feature as of yet.

Comment: Maybe this plugin is what you need: https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release ?

Comment: @Opal Thanks for your response, but I don't think a release plugin would help me here. I already have artifacts(jar and corresponding pom)published to one of the repositories hosted on the Artifactory. I would want to be able to change their versions while trying to copy them to another respository on Artifactory. I'm using AccuRev as my SCM.

Looking for a possible REST API implementation for this.

Comment: Your edit turned this into a completely different question (and now your links don't seem relevant). What exactly are you trying to do? If you explained your use case, it might be easier for people to help you.

Comment: The [build promotion plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/build/promotion) will promote a build, moving its artifacts to a release repository and changing the versions accordingly. This is a special case of what you're asking for (it doesn't allow you to arbitrarily choose the new version number), so it may or may not fit your use case. There's also a built-in promotion system, though I'm not sure exactly how it differs from the plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much@DarthFennec . I am a newbie to this build engineering world,especially the gradle and artifcatory. I had earlier gone through that plugin, but didn't quite understand it's usage. But now since you too mentioned it, I thought of giving it another long, hard look. I am now trying this out myself. Looks like I would need to tweak this pugin a little. Right now it seems to solve my problem, but only partly. The artifact version does change, but artifactory path patterns are still not as expected. Hopefully I'd be able to get around this too, and would again post my update here.